# Running feval() on a complex matrix

Tags: vectorization, complex-numbers, scilab, array-broadcasting

I am following Varodom Toochinda (a.k.a Dew)'s tutorial [here](https://scilabdotninja.wordpress.com/scilab-control-engineering-basics/module-1-transfer-functions-and-frequency-responses/). But I want to vectorize this piece of code:

```matlab
f = linspace(0.01, 1, 1000); // frequency vector (Hz)
w = 2 * %pi * f;  // convert to rad/s
Pmag = zeros(1, 1000); Pph = zeros(1, 1000);
for k=1:1000, // compute P(jw) at each frequency point
  P = 1 / (-10 * w(k)^2 + 0.1 * %i * w(k)); 
  [Pmag(k), Pph(k)] = polar(P);
end
```

to

```matlab
f = linspace(0.01, 1, 1000); // frequency vector (Hz)
w = 2 * %pi * f;  // convert to rad/s
P = 1 ./ (-10 * w.^2 + 0.1 * %i * w);
[Pmag, Pph_rad] = feval(P, polar);
```

but I get the

> feval: Wrong number of output argument(s): 1 expected.

error. and if I try just the `feval(P, polar)` command, I get the

> feval: Wrong type for input argument #1 : A real matrix expected.

error message. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As (quite poorly but anyway) documented in the [feval() help page](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.1/en_US/feval.html) :

1. *`f` is an [external] (function or routine) accepting on one or two arguments **which are supposed to be real**.*
2. Accepted synopses are
   `z = feval(x,y,f)` and `z = feval(x,f)`
   that **support only one output argumen**t. So,`[Pmag, Pph_rad] = feval(P, polar);` can't be a legal call.

For your user case, since `polar` works only in a matricial way that is not the required one, just avoid it:

```
P = 1 ./ (-10 * w.^2 + 0.1 * %i * w);
[Pmag, Pph] = (abs(P), atan(imag(P),real(P)));
```

About `polar` evolutions, do not hesitate to comment the reports [#13486](http://bugzilla.scilab.org/13486) and [#16806](http://bugzilla.scilab.org/16806#c1).

Comment: Hi Samuel, Thanks a lot for answering my question. It is great to have you and @stéphane-mottelet over here. I tried sending an email to your `...@free.fr` but it bounced back. Anyway, it would be great to have you and Stéphane on [#scilab ' s Discord channel](https://discord.gg/XCAxqUQ).

Comment: `I tried sending an email to your ...@free.fr but it bounced back` : ?! maybe gmail.com is black-listed on the mail server of my internet provider? Is it possible to mail to someone in private with the SO interface?

Comment: Hi Samuel, no SO doesn't allow that. Do you have any other email addresses? Maybe you can send me an email to `f.s.farimani@gmail.com`?

Comment: Should we open a bug report for `feval()` as well? It is most certainly not compliant with the MATLAB functionality.

Comment: That can't be an issue by itself. Scilab has never aimed to be compliant with any other software, nor to ask other softwares to be compliant with it. But you may ask for adding or extending a feature because you need it. That's something else. Then, describe the feature, without just saying "Hey just look at /this software/ and do the same". About `feval`, i agree that it is currently very limited. But i never use it. It's far preferable to vectorize functions. By the way, using it on a unvectorized macro does not speed calls very much.  Some benchmarks could be added to monitor performances.

Comment: Samuel, I still have difficulties sending emails to your `...@free.fr ` email. Can you be kind to share another email of yours? Maybe Gmail? I could send you direct massages on Discord as well if that's your preference.